# Is the following trigonometric identity true?

Tags: trigonometry

I can't prove the following trigonometry identity:

$$\tan(2x)\tan(30^\circ-x)+\tan(2x)\tan(60^\circ-x)+\tan(60^\circ-x)\tan(30^\circ-x)=1$$

Is it true and if yes how should I proceed?

Comment: Use $\tan(a\pm b)=\frac{\tan(a)\pm\tan(b)}{1\mp\tan(a)\tan(b)}$ and see in what it becomes as a function of $\tan(x)$.

Comment: I did that but it becomes too complicated and the denominators are different...

Comment: FYI: The identity is true. It's even true if you replace $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ with any two complementary angles (say, $a$ and $90^\circ - a$).

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $y=\tan(x)$. Taking into account what Blue said it might look better if we just assume any complementary angles instead of $30$ and $60$.

Let's write $r=\tan(a)$ and $s=\tan(90-a)$. We know that $rs=1$.

Then the left-hand side becomes

$$\frac{2y}{1-y^2}\frac{r-y}{1+yr}+\frac{2y}{1-y^2}\frac{s-y}{1+ys}+\frac{r-y}{1+yr}\frac{s-y}{1+ys}$$

Then the function above becomes

$$\frac{2y(r-y)(1+ys)+2y(s-y)(1+yr)+(1-y^2)(r-y)(s-y)}{(1-y^2)(1+yr)(1+ys)}$$

The numerator seems to expand to 
$$3rsy^2+rs-ry^3+ry-sy^3+sy-y^4-3y^2=1-ry^3+ry-sy^3+sy-y^4$$

and the denominator to 
$$-rsy^4+rsy^2-ry^3+ry-sy^3+sy-y^2+1=-y^4-ry^3+ry-sy^3+sy+1$$

where we used that $rs=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan[30^\circ-x+(60^\circ-x)]=\frac{\tan(30^\circ-x)+\tan(60^\circ-x)}{1-\tan(30^\circ-x)\tan(60^\circ-x)}\  \ \ \ (1)$$

$$\tan[30^\circ-x+(60^\circ-x)]=\tan(90^\circ-2x)=\cot2x=\dfrac1{\tan2x}\  \ \ \ (2)$$

Equate $(1),(2)$ and simplify